# Multiclass SVM Training is taking too long

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I started training my image dataset which consists of 18 classes (The dataset is a collection of compound facial emotions) and each class consists a maximum of 75 images since 10 in the morning. I am implementing SVM algorithm for it and I used the GridSearchCV to get the best model. It’s been 15 hours already and my code block is still executing on Jupyter Notebook as of the moment.

I defined a param_grid variable which consists of different values for C, Gamma and Kernel.

```
param_grid={‘C’:[0.1,1,10,100],’gamma’:[0.0001,0.001,0.1,1],’kernel’:[‘rbg’,’poly’,’linear’]}
```

For the first two hours of executing the code block, Python’s CPU usage was at around 60-70%. After the first two hours, Python’s CPU usage dropped to 10-12%. I am not sure if there is still progress going on after the CPU Usage dropped, because it’s been 15 hours already. I am using Ryzen 5 5600 and has 16GB of RAM.

Is this still normal? I am starting to worry because I don’t know if my dataset is big or Python isn’t making a progress even though the code block haven’t finished executing. Any advice or tips? What kernel is recommended for my dataset?

Here's my full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.io import imread
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,accuracy_score,confusion_matrix
import pickle

Categories = ['Anger', 'AngrilyDisgusted', 'AngrilySurprised', 'Disgust', 
        'DisgustedlySurprised', 'Fear', 'FearfullyAngry', 'FearfullySurprised',
          'HappilyDisgusted', 'HappilySurprised', 'Happiness', 'Neutral',
          'SadlyAngry', 'SadlyDisgusted', 'SadlyFearful', 'SadlySurprised',
          'Sadness', 'Surprise']
flat_data_arr=[] #input array
target_arr=[] #output array
datadir='Batch1_Training_75/' 
#path which contains all the categories of images
for i in Categories:
    
    print(f'loading... category : {i}')
    path=os.path.join(datadir,i)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array=imread(os.path.join(path,img))
        img_resized=resize(img_array,(150,150,3))
        flat_data_arr.append(img_resized.flatten())
        target_arr.append(Categories.index(i))
    print(f'loaded category:{i} successfully')
flat_data=np.array(flat_data_arr)
target=np.array(target_arr)
df=pd.DataFrame(flat_data) #dataframe
df['Target']=target
x=df.iloc[:,:-1] #input data 
y=df.iloc[:,-1] #output data

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.20,random_state=77,stratify=y)
print('Splitted Successfully')

param_grid={‘C’:[0.1,1,10,100],’gamma’:[0.0001,0.001,0.1,1],’kernel’:[‘rbg’,’poly’,’linear’]}
svc=svm.SVC(probability=True)
print("The training of the model is started, please wait for while as it may take few minutes to complete")
model=GridSearchCV(svc,param_grid)
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
print('The Model is trained well with the given images')
model.best_params_
```

Comment: please share more code, it is hard to see how resources are allocated from just this line

Comment: Sorry. There you go, I added the whole code at the end.

Comment: have you specified the number of jobs in your grid search? 
model = GridSearchCV(svc, param_grid, n_jobs=-1) will use all the CPU cores and should speed things up

Comment: Ohh sadly I haven't. Will try that again!

Answer (score 0):

SVMs do not scale so well and as per [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html):

> The fit time scales at least quadratically with the number of samples
> and may be impractical beyond tens of thousands of samples. For large
> datasets consider using LinearSVC or SGDClassifier instead, possibly
> after a Nystroem transformer.

Therefore the number of samples can indeed be a bottleneck in your case. As suggested by the docs, use `LinearSVC` and see if your performance improves.

One the other hand (if you are still inclined to use SVM), a better way would be to randomly sample few data points as for SVM all data points are not needed anyways to form the decision boundary (or **support vectors**). It may be a good way to discard around 85-90% of the data and see the classification performance.